# Design patterns for user dropdown on top right corner

Tags: design-patterns, design, user-preferences

Is there any design pattern for user drop-down which will be on top right corner of the application?

I want to know some best possible features of this control.

Please share some ideas.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what the reason for that would be unless your target audience is left handed. May I ask why you are looking to it that way? If you do have to do it that way, I would use a floating hamburger menu for sure.